# Global variables and basic blocks

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I want to support global variables in my tiny compiler. Do I need to make a "global" basic block which would hold all other basic blocks and global variables, or I can keep global variables outside?

Comment: A basic block contains code, not data. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

As [@EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) said, basic blocks contain **code**. So, even if you create a BB that would contain some `alloca`s, you would need to wrap this into a function first, and thus, these variables would become local variables of that function.

So, if you want global variables, read appropriate [reference section](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#globalvars) for description of how it works.